# Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express edition - APPCRASH

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am not able to execute my VC++ program on Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition. It displays an error saying the .exe has stopped working. The problem event name is APPCRASH. Could you please tell me how to fix it. I am unable to run any program.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to start the application in the debugger? Or you can to take a look into the problem signature, which should be offered by the error dialog.

Kim